How many sound characteristics are transformed in analog to digital audio conversion?
I'm curious about the process of converting analog audio to digital audio. When sound, which has various characteristics like pitch, timbre, frequency, loudness, amplitude, phase, harmonic content, and dynamic range, is converted to digital audio, which of these characteristics are preserved or transformed in the digital format?

https://xiph.org/video/vid2.shtml - Monty Montgomery's digital sampling show & tell shows how digital sampling can and does reconstruct an arbitrary signal (assuming it was already bandwidth-limited to 20kHz before sampling).  The output isn't a stair-step version of it, it's the original signal.  He uses some physical hardware like a signal generator and an analogue oscilloscope; great video.  (Monty designed the Ogg Vorbis and Opus audio compression codecs.  Only with lossy compression like that or MP3 or AAC are you throwing away some information from the signal.)

How many push-ups can Chuck Norris do? ;-)

All of those characteristics are preserved.
Music is, after all, sound, and sound is changes of air pressure. Digitally recording from a microphone is a straightforward task:

Measure air pressure deviation from the average, express it using voltage

Measure voltage, convert to number. Now we have a number for air pressure deviation.

Store number.


Our ears do the same thing, except they use a mechanical arrangement to convert air pressure expressed relative to time to air pressure expressed as frequencies, amplitudes and phases over time. Those then get converted to electrical impulses.
Pop music production tends to process the original sound rather heavily so it does alter most of the characteristics you speak of. But it’s not a property of digital recording itself. It’s just the process applied to the data after the recording.
And if you worry that this double conversion: first to voltage, then to a number, seems convoluted - it may be so but we can do it very, very well.
There are direct-conversion microphones that instead of converting pressure to voltage, use a mechanical balance scale. The scale is pressed on by the air pressure on one side, and by electrical forces on the other. The electrical forces are applied in very short, frequent pulses under feedback to keep the scale balanced. These pulses are counted over time and provide a digital (numerical) representation of air pressure changes.

That's a bit like asking which elements of a brush stroke in a painting is preserved in a digital color photograph or print.  The recording is not done for reproducing the higher aspects of the original but for creating sensations that are a high-quality substitute of the original with regard to the human senses.  In the case of a color photograph, that means condensing a continuum of wavelengths into just three primary color components that have a high correlation with the differences human eye receptors can distinguish.
You couldn't fool a mantis shrimp.  In a similar vein, digital reproduction of music is focused about the frequencies and dynamic ranges accessible to human hearing and are anything but faithful to cats and dogs, let alone bats.  There is a hard cut-off for common media at about 20kHz, corresponding to the 20-20kHz hearing range of an adult(!) listener, and MP3 or other lossy compression (like JPEG for images) tries to throw away lots more of information that is unlikely to register to human senses in the total experience though it will yield to more detailed analysis in particular when looking very closely.  Both with regard to acoustic and visual compression there have been quite more elaborate methods developed by now that act more gracefully under closeup scrutiny, but they have not taken over significant ground because of the "good enough" factor.
Stored sampling rate and resolution for audio provide hard thresholds of what information a recording can preserve in terms of maximum contained frequency and dynamic range.  CD quality at 44.1kHz (corresponding to an information cut-off beyond 22.05kHz) and 16bit is comparatively good here, but various ways of processing music cause frequency-dependent artifacts (digital IIR filter equivalents to analog filters have warped frequency responses when approaching the highest feasible frequencies and some non-linear manipulations bleed into lower frequencies), so for processing and mixing, 96kHz at 24bit is often employed, with the final downsampling occuring just when creating the physical media.
44.1kHz which is tied into video norms in a weird manner also tends no longer to be used except for CD production (which may or may not be processed at 88.2kHz which is more amicable to down-process into 44.1kHz sampling than 96kHz is), with 48kHz (and its multiples) being more prevalent.
All this is in categories of pressure samples in a numerically and temporally fine-grained grid.
A higher-level description concerned more about items like musical pitch, timbre, loudness and so on would be MIDI.  As a consequence, MIDI files of orchestral arrangements tend to be ridiculously small in size but are limited in reproductive power and cannot represent the characteristic sounds, timbres, and voice of solo instrumental and vocal performers and specific instruments.  For backing tracks and film music, they can do a marvelous job, depending on the quality of the respective MIDI expanders converting the MIDI back into sound samples.

The level of fidelity depends on which sampling rate you will use and how many bits per sample.
Audio is just a voltage signal on wire. It might come from a microphone that converts the air pressure signal into electrical, or go to a speaker that converts it back to air pressure signal.
You just need high enough sampling rate and enough bits per sample to reconstruct the waveform closely enough so ears cannot distinguish any difference in the air pressure signal.
Of course telephone has limited bandwidth due to low sampling and bits per sample so it cannot reproduce the original signal without loss.
However a CD as a storage medium can basically be said to store everything and maybe even more your ears are able to detect. It uses 44.1 kHz and 16 bits per sample.
If you go a bit higher like 48 kHz and 18 to 20 bits, it should be good enough for even most demanding applications. Many devices use internally higher sampling rates and bit depths for processing and perhaps to allow further editing, 96 kHz at 24 bits might be common, 192 kHz with 32-bits or floating point might also be used.

If done the right way, all of them.
All digitizing audio does is sample the voltage repeatedly and store a number representing the voltage for each sample. The things that will affect the quality of the resulting data is how often the sampling is done and the bit depth.
In order to avoid aliasing and reproduce the signal faithfully, sampling must be done above the Nyquist rate, twice the highest frequency contained in the signal. The dynamic range will depend on how many bits are used, for example 8 bits will give you 256 possible voltage levels, 16 bits will give you 65536 possible values. The more bits the more detail that can be represented.

The Nyquist frequency is misunderstood. Its double is by no means adequate to sample an arbitrary signal. At Nyquist, sampling gives accurate amplitude only for exactly phase-aligned sine wave. That is not what we want at all when acquiring data. Instead, we have to sample at a rate many times higher.

@Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica That is a handwavy view. A digital signal at a specific sampling frequency uniquely represents a band-limited signal right up to the Nyquist frequency. A sine signal slightly below Nyquist frequency looks like a slowly beating signal at Nyquist frequency which is a superposition of the original signal and one slightly above Nyquist frequency.  Since reconstruction removes the second signal, the original remains.  We only need higher sampling frequencies because reconstruction (digital as oversampling and analog with filters) is less than perfect.

@Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica You are mathematically correct about the theorem, the sampling rate must be larger, being larger or equal is not enough. In practice in everyday communication it is said to be twice the bandwidth even if more than twice is correct. Basically at the sampling rate the amplitude should be well below ADC dynamic range anyway so the equality in the strict mathematical sense is rather irrelevant from that point of view.

@Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica: Many times higher than Nyquist?  So you're claiming that a 44.1kHz or 48kHz sample rate aren't adequate to sample and reconstruct an arbitrary signal bandwidth-limited to 20kHz, because they're only a bit above 2x the signal bandwidth?  Especially 48kHz has a decent amount of headroom (for filter rolloff), so with 16-bit samples you're still pretty far from a point where +-1 in a sample could give wildly different amplitude vs. phase to a 20kHz sine.  If you're going to do your filtering digitally to band-limit the signal, then maybe you'd want a higher freq there?

@PeterCordes The thing is, modern ADCs do not sample at e.g. 48 kHz and 16 bits. It is far cheaper and better as a result in whole to have a simple analog filter and sample at much higher frequency and less bits and use digital signal processing to do conversion and have the ADC output 48 kHz at 16 bits. Compare that to say the early CD player which did use 44.1 kHz and 16 bit DAC but had to use something like 6th order analog filter to have steep enough analog filter to pass 20 kHz but block 22 kHz.

@Justme: Ok, that all makes sense, but I think is still compatible with what I said (esp. my last sentence).  A simple analog filter to band-limit the signal to say 80 kHz (potentially with distortion above 24kHz) makes the Nyquist frequency 160 kHz to avoid aliasing (potentially to sub-24kHz), so a 192 kHz sample rate would be appropriate, right?  Or do people (e.g. Kuba) tend to talk about the Nyquist frequency as the eventual target that you want to downsample to after digital filtering?  So you'd consider this setup as 192 kHz sampling above a Nyquist of 48 kHz not 160 kHz?

@Justme do you have links that describe the process you describe? This is the first time I'm hearing about sampling with low resolution at high frequency can do the same job as sampling accurately at low frequency.

@horta It's called oversampling. For example DSD bitstream on SACD discs is 1-bit audio sampled at 2.822 MHz ( 44100 × 64). Sigma-delta converters may output the 1-bit or multibit oversampled stream, or downsample it to 44100 Hz 16-bit data.

Nyquist is indeed widely misunderstood, including by @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica. It's a band width. Signals at half the sample rate will alias those at DC, but this is only a problem if both occur in the input. If the input is known to contain no DC component, reconstruction can recover the signal (including phase) at half the sample rate. And if the input has no components below half the sample rate, reconstruction can even recover up to the whole same rate. It's even possible to reconstruct signals above the sample rate, given a sufficiently band-limited input.
